# How to set the background color of material ui drawer component with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

## Background

I'm using a [Material ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/) draw in my application along with [Styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/). I have read the documentation for styling Material ui components with Styled components and have it working for several simple ones.

## Problem

Changing the background color doesn't follow what I expected. simply adding the style in a styled component seems to apply the styles at the wrong level.

## What I have tried

```
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledDrawer = styled(Drawer)`
        background-color: red;
`;
```

## Conclution

From what I can see I need to style the inner section known as the Paper component. I do not see a way to do that with styled components.

## Question

Is it possible to style this hidden paper component in a material ui drawer with styled components?

Answer (score 7):

To style the inner components from the drawer (or other components that works like this) you have to override the class name of the component you want to, here it is how to use:

https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

---

To be quicker: You just have to create the style as you would for any other component, then you do

`<Drawer classes={{ paper: classes.theNameOfTheStyleClass }} />`

This way you are overriding the style of an especific component (the Paper one).

In the API of the component you can check which classes you can override.

Here it is the Drawer API: https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/#css-api

Hope it may help you :3

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not using the library `styled-components`

Comment: It used to be the best solution before matria UI 4.0.0. Now it seems something is broken when I try to set the background color to Drawer

Answer (score 6):

Yes you are correct - your style was working but it was being overridden due to the paper style being more specific.

Yes you can do this with style-components by styling the div below the drawer:

```
const StyledDrawer = styled(Drawer)`
  & > div {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;
```

Here is a working codepen: https://codesandbox.io/embed/50mp1nnx94?fontsize=14

You can't do it with class names becuase these are generated and inserted at run time so the "paper" class will actually be called something like "MuiDrawer-paper-2579" where you won't know the number in advance.

Comment: It's been forever since you posted this, but just wanted to say it really helped me out! Thank you :)